# how to set the Arial font style for drawing text

Tags: ios

I use the next code for creating a png file. I need to write some text with the Arial 24. How can I do this? I can not find where I can set the Arial font style.

```
UIImage *image = [BSSharedObject getInstance].downloadedImage;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HEIGHT), NO, 1.0);
[message drawInRect:CGRectMake(INDENT, INDENT, WIDTH - 2 *INDENT ,600) withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake((WIDTH - INDENT - image.size.width), (HEIGHT - INDENT- image.size.height), image.size.width, image.size.height)];
UIImage *resultImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[BSSharedObject getInstance].createdImage = resultImage;

UIImage *im =  [BSSharedObject getInstance].createdImage;
return resultImage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:24]`

This will get you your desired font. Calling `systemFontOfSize` predictably results in the return of a *system* font - in the case of iOS you get `Helvetica Neue`.

Comment: Note: Arial's font name is actually explicitly listed as `@"ArialMT"` in iOS. It would be prudent to use the explicit name.